# Why does my background image distort when viewed on a MacBook?

Tags: ios, css, macos, background

My page has a full screen background image, using `cover`. On Windows machines this looks fine, but when viewed on a MacBook, the image looks stretched and "cloudy". Why has this happened? My CSS is below:

```
background: url("images/backgroundimage.jpg");
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
background-attachment:fixed;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: Which browsers are you testing on on each machine? Are the monitors of different resolutions? If your MacBook has a much greater resolution than your PC, it could be that the image simply has to stretch more on the former. Try using a bigger background image and see if this solves/improves the situation.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin i have tested it on all browsers on MacBook and Windows

Comment: Have you tried the resolution check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Macbook has a retina display. That's why your image is getting distort and stretched. If that is the case, you need to use retina ready images (that is 2X larger that the image you are currently using) to solve this problem.

Here is a nice article about retina ready website. [A guide for creating a better retina web](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/a-guide-for-creating-a-better-retina-web/).

Take a look. It might solve your problem.